# How to show a dropdown selected value in the same page in laravel?

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, parameter-passing, selection, data-retrieval

I have a database table named country(id,country,capital).I have retried the country name through dropdwon selection list. I want that when I will select a option from the dropdown ,the capital name will be shown the the same view page .
Here my view page..

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Country name</h3>
         <select class="form-control" name="country_id">
          <option>Select Country</option>
            
          @foreach ($countries as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}"> 
                {{ $value->country }} 
            </option>
          @endforeach    
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <h3>Capital name</h3>
       <div style="width: 100%;height: 150px;border:3px solid black">
          <p>Capital name:</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Here the controller ..

class CountryController extends Controller
{

```
public function index()
{
    
    $countries=Country::all();

   return view('country', compact('countries'));
}


}
```

My expected output will be:

---

Capital name:Istanbul

Comment: You need to do that with ajax, with js onChange event

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use JavaScript.

Example:

First add **onchange="displayCountryName(this.value)"** on your **select element**.

Secondly,replace p element with a disabled input element add an id to your **input element** like so, **id="countryName"**

```php
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Country name</h3>
             <select class="form-control" onchange="displayCountryName(this.value)" name="country_id">
              <option>Select Country</option>
                
              @foreach ($countries as $key => $value)
                <option value="{{ $key }}"> 
                    {{ $value->country }} 
                </option>
              @endforeach    
            </select>
    
    
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <h3>Capital name</h3>
           <div style="width: 100%;height: 150px;border:3px solid black">
              Capital name: <input disabled id="countryName">
           </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
```

for your JS

```
 function displayCountryName(value)
{
    document.getElementById('countryName').value = value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the HTML code..

```
    <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Country name</h3>
         <select class="form-control" onchange="capitalName(this.value)" name="country_id">
          <option>Select Country</option>
            
          @foreach ($countries as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}"> 
                {{ $value->country }} 
            </option>
          @endforeach    
        </select>


    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <h3>Capital name</h3>
       <div style="width: 100%;height: 150px;border:3px solid black">
          Capital name: <input disabled id="countryName">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this should b your javascript code...

```
function capitalName(cap){
  document.getElementById('countryName').value = cap;
}
```

[here is the working code for referance](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/pox528wL/21/)